# Blocking Infrared Signals

Tags: signal-processing, infrared-radiation

I am currently working on a project that involves infrared signals. This project has an infrared receiver, but I would like for it to receive signals from front side only. For example, if the signal source is coming from behind/left/right of the receiver, the receiver should not output anything. Are there any good materials that can completely block or cutoff infrared signals? I already tried nail polish and aluminum foils but they are not working.

The infrared signal source is a remote control by the way.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Foil does block IR.   Is it possible that the IR from behind your receiver is reflecting from objects in front?

Comment: Almost everything should block IR for your purpose.  I agree with commenter above, likely you have some reflection.

Comment: I tried some tests if reflection is the cause by transmitting a signal along the line of sight but against the receiver, and it showed no readings. So therefore, maybe reflection is not the cause of what I am experiencing.

Comment: Internal heat source?  How sensitive is the detector?

Comment: Try https://engineering.stackexchange.com if your question would be here closed.